# UITableView add caption to an image icon

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to make a tableview that displays Bluetooth devices nearby and their signal strength. I have an image icon displaying the signal strength in bars using cell.imageview.image. I'd like to add a caption below the image showing the decibel value of the signal, just like LightBlue does it. How would I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can actually set the style of a UITableViewCell either in storyboard or programmatically to either UITableViewCellStyleDefault, UITableViewCellStyleValue1, UITableViewCellStyleValue2, or UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle. You can view how these styles look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW14.  Is subtitle the one you are looking for?

If you are creating the cell programmatically, you do:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
```

To set the subtitle you do:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Your subtitle";
```

If you would like some other custom look, then you can subclass UITableViewCell and create your own style cell and layout.